# cant seem to figure out the error: get_queryset() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a django rest framework project. I created a viewset and I am setting up the urls for the viewset. I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError at /api/v2/preferences/
get_queryset() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I am working with the preferences urls...

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('dashboards/<int:pk>', dashboard_detail, name='dashboard-detail'),
    path('dashboards/<str:guid>', dashboard_detail, name='dashboard-detail'),
    path('users/<int:pk>/stacks/', person_stack, name='user-stacks'),
    path('preferences/<str:namespace>/<str:path>/<int:pk>/', user_preference_stack, 
         name='preferences-pk'),
    path('preferences/<str:namespace>/<str:path>/', user_preference_stack, 
         name='preferences-path'),
    path('preferences/<str:namespace>/', user_preference_stack, name='preferences-namespace'),
    path('preferences/', user_preference_stack, name='preferences')
]
```

I also wanted to know if it is possible to create 1 url with the namespace and path as optional and not required arguments rather than 4 urls with each variation of the url.
here is the viewset:

```
class PreferenceUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Preference
    serializer_class = PreferenceSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == 'create' or self.action == 'destroy' or self.action == 'list' or self.action == 'put':
            permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
        else:
            permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]

    def get_user(self):
        return self.request.user

    def get_queryset(self):
        namespace = self.kwargs.get('namespace', None)
        path = self.kwargs.get('path', None)
        if namespace is None and path is None:
            queryset = Preference.objects.all().filter(person=self.request.user.id)
        if namespace and path is None:
            queryset = Preference.objects.all().filter(
                person=self.request.user.id,
                namespace=namespace)
        if namespace and path:
            queryset = Preference.objects.all().filter(
                person=self.request.user.id,
                namespace=namespace,
                path=path)
        return queryset

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        namespace = self.kwargs.get('namespace', None)
        path = self.kwargs.get('path', None)
        if namespace is None and path is None:
            return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if namespace and path is None:
            data = {
                "person": request.user.id,
                'version': request.data.get('version'),
                'namespace': namespace,
                'path': request.data.get('path'),
                'value': request.data.get('value'),
                'user_id': request.user.id,
            }

        if namespace and path:
            data = {
                "person": request.user.id,
                'version': request.data.get('version'),
                'namespace': namespace,
                'path': path,
                'value': request.data.get('value'),
                'user_id': request.user.id,
            }
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        namespace = self.kwargs.get('namespace', None)
        path = self.kwargs.get('path', None)
        if namespace and path:
            try:
                instance = self.get_object()
                self.perform_destroy(instance)
            except Http404:
                pass
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        namespace = self.kwargs.get('namespace', None)
        path = self.kwargs.get('path', None)
        primary = self.kwargs.get('pk', None)
        instance = self.queryset.get(
            user_id=request.user.id,
            namespace=namespace,
            path=path,
            pk=primary)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(instance, data=request.data, partial=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

full stack track:

```
TypeError at /api/v2/preferences/
get_queryset() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/preferences/
Django Version: 2.2.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
get_queryset() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Exception Location: C:\Users\jandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py in dispatch, line 492
Python Executable:  C:\Users\jandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\jandali\\Desktop\\o-backend\\ozone-framework-python-server',
 'C:\\Users\\jandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\jandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\jandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\jandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32',
 'C:\\Users\\jandali\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\jandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 16 Jul 2019 19:32:02 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Users\jandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\jandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\jandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\jandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py in wrapped_view
        return view_func(*args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\jandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py in view
            return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\jandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py in dispatch
            response = self.handle_exception(exc) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\jandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py in handle_exception
            self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\jandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py in dispatch
            response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
```

Comment: According to [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_querysetself) I think you should use `self.get_queyset()` instead of `self.queryset` which you are using in `partial_update`.

Comment: i tried that and it gave me a different error

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: You are not covering all cases in `get_queryset`. You will get an error if `queryset` variable is not set. Put `queryset = Preference.objects.all()` as the first line in `get_queryset` function.

Comment: I am getting the same error still `TypeError at /api/v2/preferences/
get_queryset() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` @Ivan

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace?

Comment: added the full stack trace to the original postj @Ivan

Comment: as @Ivan told you must use `self.get_queryset()` instead `self.queryset` . and are you sure in `def get_queryset()` in this part `        if namespace and path:
            queryset = Preference.objects.all().filter(
                person=self.request.user.id,
                namespace=namespace,
                path=path)` your person is just an integer?i think you need replace `person = self.request.user` or `person_id=self.request.user.id` . after done this changes put error here.